TX and RX of UART are not connected to the board
I am looking in a TP-Link router and found an UART port. While I could determine the Volt and Ground ports using a multimeter, I couldn't distinguish between the TX and RX ports (two pin on the right) because they both displayed zero voltage on the multimeter. I soldered them anyway and attempted to read the data on minicom, but no data was transmitted. After some research, I found out that TP-Link routers often have the RX not connected to the board, and requiring manual resoldering. Thus, I suspect that in my case, both the RX and TX ports are not connected to the board.
My questions are:

How can I determine if the TX and RX ports are connected to the board?
How can I resoldering them to connect to the board?"



Use a multimeter set to continuity mode to check for a direct electrical connection between the UART pins and the corresponding points on the main board.


You can't determine TX and RX if they are unconnected. You might not be able to determine TX and RX anyway, if they are not used by the firmware. Even it they can be used, both pins may look like identical inputs, until you send a correct sequence of commands at correct baud rate to unlock the TX output.

There are multiple components missing, such as transistors used maybe for level conversion between some low IO voltage to higher UART voltage.


The port may not even be an UART port, but something else, like I2C or SWD.

From your photo, it's quite clear that some components are missing (Q6, Q9, R69, R73, R76 and R78, if I'm reading it correctly). Of course, there could also be other parts missing if there are traces on any other layers.
Just because it's a 4-pin header with power and ground, does not mean it's definately a UART. The topology looks the same for both of these pins, which isn't something you'd typically expect for 1x input and 1x output signal. You could try probing the other side of Q6 / Q9 to see if any signals are present - though even if it is a UART, there could be some activation sequence or firmware modification (e.g: device tree) required to enable the UART in the first place.


How can I determine if the TX and RX ports are connected to the board?

These pins are connected to "the board", but appear to be disconnected from the rest of the circuitry by no-fit components.

How can I resoldering them to connect to the board?"

Depending on the purpose of Q6 / Q9, it could be as simple as wiring across two pins of the footprint... though you may also need to take care with voltage levels if these implement level conversion (e.g: from 1.8v internal signals to 3.3v tolerant signals on the pins)... Start by probing these pads to see what you find.
